# What is the right way to insert inline server tags on a page's css section?

Tags: asp.net, css, syntax-highlighting, visual-studio-2012, inline

I'm trying to put some inline server tags on a page so I can get the right path for an image, using Visual Studio 2012.

I'm doing it like  this:

```
<style type="text/css">
.someclass
{
    background-image: url(<%=Url.Content("~/Content/Images/messageIcon.gif")%>);
}
</style>
```

The problem is that once this is written, the whole style section loses the color formatting withing the VS2012 editor. Is tyhere a different way to do this (or an option in VS2012), so that I won't lose the colors and the indentation?

Comment: Why isn't this declared in an external CSS file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason that visual studio is losing its formating is that you are mixing css and server-side code as below.

```
<style type="text/css"> 
.someclass  
{     
    background-image: url(<%=Url.Content("~/Content/Images/messageIcon.gif")%>);
}    
</style>
```

You should separate your css from your code.

Image paths are relative to the location of the css file, so css like below is correct, therefore you do not need use a application path worked out by Url.Content(~)

```
.someclass  
{     
     background-image: url(../Images/messageIcon.gif); 
}
```

Comment: What if those css rules are on a master page? The Views that load based on the master have different locations than that of the mater page. I would need to add more ../ depending on the view's location in order to get the right path.

Comment: The point is that (as per cimmanon's comment) your CSS should be separated from your aspx. Style's images added in the way that you are trying causes Visual Studio formatting problems, as you are using server tags within CSS. In a separate CSS file the image path is then relative to the css.

Comment: Its tempting to mix the css and server-side code but you really are better off keeping it separate for many reasons including Visual Studio throwing a formatting wobbly!

Answer (score 3):

That is a Visual Studio Highlight issue or feature for css styles. Try to use server relative URLs, that are known.

If you need to insert a server-side code into css styles, you can use `style` attribute in html-markup. For example:

```
<div class="beautiful-button" style="background-image: url('<%=Url.Content("~/Content/Images/messageIcon.gif")%>')">
...
</div>
```

If you don't like this code or you need to use it more than one time in different places, the best way would be to create your own server-side control with a public property URL (for example). Finally it will be looked like this:

```
<asp:MyOwnControl runat="server" class="beautiful-button" URL="~/Content/Images/messageIcon.gif" />
```

Comment: The thing is I don't always know the relative URL for the View since these syles are used on a Master Page.

Comment: Yes. You are correct, but as I understand, the idea of master page is to provide a template for a content page. So, the best way would be to override master page styles in the content page. I think, that a master page don't need to know about content pages. Do you agree with me?

Comment: Yes, you're right. But in this case, for example, we have a style for a button. This style is used in all views that inherit the master page. I would have to repeat the style on all views, which would defeat the purpose of the master page, which holds everything that is common to all Views.

Comment: Ok, I see. I think, there is no way to use a correct Highlight for your code. May be using of "style" attributes in html-markup will resolve your problems.